# Django 1.11.5 Class based (generic) redirect function with args

Tags: python, django, redirect

Within my created application within Django 1.11.5 I have created update, create and delete functionality using ClassBased or Generic views which do work, however I am having a problem redirecting my user to correct dynamic page. In a instatcne if a user has opened a details page for a specific product, when the user updates the product infromation I want the application to redirect user back to the updated page. As of yet I have achieved this using args by specifing a specific id, which obsiously redirects to specified page but not dynamic.

Any help or assitance regarding the topic would be trully appriciated.

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class CommentUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['comment_body']

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', args=(2,)) #how to make this part dynamic
```

example of detail view.

```
class DetailsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'details.html'
```

**urls.py** (just in case)

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailsView.as_view(), name="detail"),
url(r'review/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.CommentUpdate.as_view(), name="comment-update"),
```

Comment: Does `Comment` have a foreign key field to `Product`?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes it does, everything works great within models.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the correct `Product` id dynamically based on the current `Comment` which you should be able to reference in its [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) via `self.object`. Assuming `product` is the name of the according `ForeignKey`, you can do:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('detail', args=(self.object.product_id,))
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview):

> While this view is executing, **self.object** will contain the object that the view is operating upon.